# Code for calculating the percentage not working

Tags: android, calculator

I don't know how to get the result from the **price** and **percent** to show the price after discount!!

```
        // write the percentage
    final EditText editPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPrice);
    // write the price
    final EditText ePercent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ePercent);
    // Hopefully to get the result
    final TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewResult);

    Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
    buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                double price = Double.valueOf(editPrice.getText()
                        .toString());
                // percent
                double per = (price / 100.0f) * ePercent;;

                result.setText(String.valueOf(per));
```

Any Help!
Thanks!

Comment: For me, your final price is `double finalPrice = price - per`. No ?

Comment: I guess you forgot to TypeCast **ePercent** to double..

Comment: How to do that? I already Cast the price to double!!

Comment: like you done with **editPrice**..

Comment: well said @JgdshSeerm post it as a answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
            // getting value from editPrice and parsing to double
            double price = Double.parseDouble(editPrice.getText().toString());

            // same like that getting value from ePercent and parsing to double
            double ePer = Double.parseDouble(ePercent.getText().toString());

            // percent
            double per = (price / 100.0f) * ePer;;

            result.setText(String.valueOf(per));
            // or
            result.setText(""+per);
```

Comment: @user3051834 That calculates the discount, not the price after discount!

Comment: @ramaral.. yes, you are right! but your method giving me error!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
buttonConvert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            double price = Double.parseDouble(editPrice.getText()
                    .toString());
            // percent
            double ePercent = Double.parseDouble(ePercent.getText()
                    .toString());

            //if ePercent between 0 and 1
                double result = price * (1.0f - ePercent);
            //if ePercent between 0 and 100
                double result = price * ((100.0f - ePercent)/100.0f);

            result.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3051834 You must choose only one result calculation - ePercent between 0 and 1 **or** ePercent between 0 and 100